# Memory spike before dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm going through my code fixing retain cycles. I just finished this on one view controller and now dealloc is getting called again (I just have a log in it to check). Watching the memory graphic though I can see a huge spike after I dismiss the controller and just before dealloc is called. Is this normal behaviour?

The spike occurs about 2 seconds after the view has dismissed and the dealloc log I print appears just after the spike peaks.

```
- (void)dealloc {
   NSLog(@"DEALLOC SEND");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your dealloc code block too please.

Comment: @gyer done - it's just got a log in it.

Comment: OK, need more details, iOS version and other details, maybe more code. Also, you shouldn't call dealloc empty.

Comment: Also what are the uits on the graph, how many bytes? The `NSLog()` will use memory. Use instruments to find out where the memory is being used.

Comment: @gyer I just added it to ensure retain cycles were fixed. Scale is about 0mb-180mb so it's a huge jump.

Comment: @gyer The OP is not calling `dealloc()`, the system is. Just for debugging it can be a way to insure the class instance it not caught in a retain cycle from perhaps a block operation.

Comment: If you use Instruments, you can focus on the area of the spike and get a report of what is being created during that time period.

Comment: @PhillipMills Good idea, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory spike was actually caused by the view controller I was returning to, not the one being deallocated.